# How can I find $\iiint\frac{xz}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx$ where $1≤x^2+y^2≤3, 0≤z≤3$?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, 3d, cylindrical-coordinates, bounds-of-integration

> Compute $$\iiint\frac{xz}{1+x^2+y^2}\,dz\,dy\,dx,$$ where $1≤x^2+y^2≤3, 0≤z≤3$.

I've tried it. But I'm only confused with $\theta$. I think it should be $0$ to $2\pi$, but that'll make the whole value zero. We have to solve this by the cylindrical method. Without solving for theta I get $\frac{9}{2{(π/6)-4}}$.

Comment: Yes, the answer is zero.  The region is symmetric about the yz-plane, and $f(-x,y,z)=-f(x,y,z)$, so by the same logic that $\int_{-1}^1 x/(1+x^2) dx=0$ without computing any antiderivatives, you can reason that this integral will be too.

Answer (score 2):

Passing to cylindrical coordinates
$$\begin{matrix}
x&=& r \cos \theta \\
y&=& r \sin \theta \\
z&=& z \\
\end{matrix}$$
you get
$$I= \int_0^3 \left( \int_0^{2 \pi}\left( \int_1^3 r \cdot \frac{zr \cos \theta}{1+r^2} dr\right)d \theta \right)dz$$
You can separate everything and get three integrals
$$I= \int_0^3 zdz \int_0^{2 \pi} \cos \theta d \theta \int_1^3 \frac{r^2}{1+r^2} dr$$
Since $\int_0^{2 \pi} \cos \theta d \theta =0$ the whole integral is zero.

Comment: This is missing the Jacobian.  $dxdy=rdrd\theta$, so there is a missing factor of $r$.

Comment: Yeah, but that does not matter . the whole integral is going to be zero. But i'm not sure , Is the suppose to be zero? Or something is wrong.

Comment: You are right: the Jacobian is missing, but the integral is still zero.